# ElasticSearch Get Time in Groovy Script

Tags: groovy, elasticsearch, timestamp, mvel

My application is using this script for boosting more recent items in the index:

```
(5 / ((3.16*pow(10,-11)) * abs(time() - doc[\'date\'].date.getMillis()) + 0.2)) + 1.0
```

It's written in MVEL, but as of 1.3, MVEL is deprecated for Groovy.  The script throws this error now:

```
GroovyScriptExecutionException[MissingMethodException[No signature of method: Script4.time() is applicable for argument types: () values: []\nPossible solutions: find(), dump(), find(groovy.lang.Closure), use([Ljava.lang.Object;), is(java.lang.Object), with(groovy.lang.Closure)]]
```

This sounds to me like the function for getting a millisecond timestamp is different in Groovy.  I tried `System.currentTimeMillis()`, but it gave another error saying it didn't support imports.

So how can I fix the `time()` function to work with Groovy?

Comment: Hi Jonah , If you don't mind could you please let me know how the above script is helping to boost most recent items ..?  Thanks for your help . (  I am just doing order by "updated date" descending to get the latest items . This is a date filed with time stamp . )  .. Thanks again

Comment: Not sure exactly what info you're needing, but if you check my answer below, you can see the entire usage context.

Comment: Thank you for your response and I am sorry I did miss your comment . In your question you mentioned the below lines  . I am sorry I couldn't find the reason behind using this script to boost performance . Why can not we just directly do sort by date to get the latest items , why do we have to use this script ?                                                                                             "My application is using this script for boosting more recent items in the index:

(5 / ((3.16*pow(10,-11)) * abs(time() - doc[\'date\'].date.getMillis()) + 0.2)) + 1.0"

Comment: Your lines ""My application is using this script for boosting more recent items in the index:

(5 / ((3.16*pow(10,-11)) * abs(time() - doc[\'date\'].date.getMillis()) + 0.2)) + 1.0""

Comment: @Bujji The reason I use this script is to _gently boost_ results by how recent they are.  If I just sorted by date, they would no-longer be sorted by relevance to the search query.

Comment: Thank you for your response . This is really helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you already have discovered, you need to rewrite your script in Groovy instead of MVEL. Instead of time you need to use `DateTime.now().getMillis()`. Here's an example of how you use it: http://writequit.org/org/es/index.html#time-in-groovy-script

Comment: Even though I already solved the problem, I'm marking yours as the answer since it is the most direct solution to the question I asked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I didn't find out how to get the time within the script, but it seems you can add variables to the query that are available within the script.  Here's the resulting JSON.

```
"function_score": {
    "query": /*...*/,
    "functions": [
        {
            "filter": {
                "exists": {
                    "field": "date"
                }
            },
            "script_score": {
                "params": {
                    "now": 1409001061000
                },
                "script": "(5 / ((3.16*pow(10,-11)) * abs(now - doc['date'].date.getMillis()) + 0.2)) + 1.0"
            }
        }
    ],
}
```

And my application generates the timestamp (in this case `1409001061000`).