# elasticsearch - get day of the week in text format like Monday, Tuesday etc

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I want to get the aggregation result as day of week in text format like Monday, Tuesday etc. I have the following aggregation in which I am getting the result as day of week but in number format like 1 for monday, 2 for tuesday etc.

```
"aggs": {
   "perWeekDay": {
       "terms": {
           "script": "doc['order_datetime'].date.dayOfWeek"
       }
    }
}
```

Update: I am doing this using script because I want to add custom field in kibana where I need to mention this script.

Comment: you could have a simple mapping on the client-side to map numbers to day names, right?

Comment: Yes, but I am trying to findout 
is there way in elasticsearch as doc['timestamp'].date.dayOfWeek().getAsText() I have seen this in answers(https://stackoverflow.com/a/31852124/6582942),  is there a way to get this in newer version as it's not working.

Comment: You can always try to format your date with the `EEE` pattern to get the corresponding three-letter day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved the same by doing some script work using conditions.

```
"aggs": {
   "perWeekDay": {
       "terms": {
           "script": "(doc['order_datetime'].date.dayOfWeek == 1 ? 'Monday' : (doc['order_datetime'].date.dayOfWeek == 2 ? 'Tuesday' : ((doc['order_datetime'].date.dayOfWeek == 3 ? 'Wednesday' : ((doc['order_datetime'].date.dayOfWeek == 4 ? 'Thursday' : ((doc['order_datetime'].date.dayOfWeek == 5 ? 'Friday' : ((doc['order_datetime'].date.dayOfWeek == 6 ? 'Saturday' : 'Sunday'))))))))))"
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily get that by doing this:

```
GET <YourIndexName>/_search
{
"size": 0,
"aggs": {
   "perWeekDay": {
       "terms": {
           "script": "doc['order_datetime'].value.dayOfWeekEnum.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.ROOT)"
       }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could do it like this

`doc['timestamp'].date.dayOfWeek + " (" + ["", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"][doc['timestamp'].date.dayOfWeek] + ")"`